# How do I manipulate PE characteristics with GCC

Tags: winapi, gcc, portable-executable, linker-flags

Like MSVC, I want to set PE characteristics like `High Entropy VA, Dynamic Base, etc.` with gcc. How can I do it with gcc? Currently, gcc only sets the characteristics `Executable`.

Comment: Can you do it with a post build action?

Comment: The linker has the options `--high-entropy-va` and `--dynamicbase`.